# ICMP PING Zabbix practical example

Tags: zabbix

How are you all doing?
I am not sure if i am posting on the right section/forum but i am experiencing a problem...

Can someone give me a practical example of a icmpping key for Zabbix?

I am trying to do a icmpping check using Zabbix but i am failing miserably...
Here is the command i am trying: zabbix_get -s 127.0.0.1 -k icmpping[142.251.128.68,10,500,64,100]

I expect a return of the latency of that ping command to Google... But instead i am receiving: ZBX_NOTSUPPORTED: Unsupported item key.

On Zabbix docs the syntax says: icmpping[,,,,]

I renamed accordingly but the command did not worked.
I also tested this using the Web Panel of Zabbix and i got the same message.

I am sorry if this is not the right place to post this...
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `icmpping[,,,,]` is a simple check, not an agent check. The agent can't perform a simple check.

- to check if the server/proxy can ping the host, use `icmpping[,,,,]` and test it using the web interface
- to check if the agent on the host can connect to another host, use `net.tcp.port[<ip>,port]` or `net.tcp.service[service,<ip>,<port>]`, depending on what you need, and you can test it both from the web interface and from the command line, using the `zabbix_get` syntax you already know.